# How to increment depth variable in recursion? It keeps resetting

Tags: php

I have a question like this:

> Create a function that takes in a nested array and an element and
> returns the frequency of that element by nested level.

**Example:**

> freqCount([1, 4, 4, [1, 1, [1, 2, 1, 1]]], 1) ➞ [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2,3]]  // The array has one 1 at level 0, 2 1's at level 1, and 3 1's at level 2.

So I have to use recursion since we don't know how many levels there are. I am getting the right number of occurrences of the `$el` passed but not the right level of depth because `$depth` keeps getting reset on every new call of `recurse();`

Here is the basic code:

```
<?php

function freqCount($arr, $el) {

recurse($arr, $el);

}

function recurse($a, $e) {

   $counter = 0;
     $depth = 0;
    $result = [];

    foreach($a as $k => $v) {
        if(!is_array($v) && $v === $e) {
            $counter++;
            $result[$depth] = $counter;
        } elseif(is_array($v)) {
            $depth++;
            recurse($v, $e);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);

}
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3 // Should be [2] => 3
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2 // Should be [1] => 2
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

Comment: Probably want `static $depth = 0;` also I think you'll need to decrement it somewhere also.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Nice `static` does keep track of the depth, thanks! Why would I need to decrement it? Here's the question: https://edabit.com/challenge/F96gXX2c8BvKnYiZ8

Comment: It was just a quick look, you don't need to decrement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible simplified, PHP 7.4 version of what you're looking for:

```
function freqCount(array $values, $searchValue): array
{
    $frequencies = computeFrequencies($values, $searchValue, 0);

    return array_map(
        static fn (int $depth) => [$depth, $frequencies[$depth]],
        array_keys($frequencies)
    );
}

function computeFrequencies(array $values, $searchValue, int $depth): array
{
    $frequencies = [$depth => 0];

    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if ($value === $searchValue) {
            $frequencies[$depth]++;
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            foreach (computeFrequencies($value, $searchValue, $depth + 1) as $deeperDepth => $frequency) {
                $frequencies[$deeperDepth] = ($frequencies[$deeperDepth] ?? 0) + $frequency;
            }
        }
    }

    return $frequencies;
}
```

Usage:

```
print_r(freqCount([1, 4, 4, [1, 1, [1, 2, 1, 1]]], 1));  // [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]]
print_r(freqCount([1, [2], 1, [[2]], 1, [[[2]]], 1, [[[[2]]]]], 2));  // [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1]]
```

It basically splits the task into two functions:

- `computeFrequencies` is the "private" recursive one, it takes a `$depth` parameter and returns a level => occurrences associative array,
- `freqCount` simply calls it once with `$depth = 0`, lets it do its thing then transforms the result into the desired output.

**[Demo (PHP 7.4)](https://3v4l.org/bSa2i)**

**[Demo (PHP 7.2+)](https://3v4l.org/M4Ss0)**

Comment: Excellent, thank you my friend. This was considered an "expert" question (highest difficulty) and I felt confused. Would you say this is difficult based on (I assume) coding for a living? I'm trying to improve and was hoping I could've figured it out :(

Comment: @rec0nstr I didn't dig too deep into your code but it seems like you weren't that far off. Recursive functions are quite counter-intuitive when you're not used to them, so I wouldn't worry too much about it. It comes with habit.

Comment: Thank you! Very clean, modern solution :)

Comment: FYI: I receive error about `::` when testing on the question site: *"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'fn' (T_STRING), expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)"* -- I assume it's an earlier version of PHP?

Comment: Thanks, I believe it's 7.3 -- So I think the arrow function is problematic.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately output for second input seems incorrect. Have you seen?

Comment: See question for more details: https://edabit.com/challenge/F96gXX2c8BvKnYiZ8

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for clarification.

Comment: I've updated my answer and also made sure when an occurrence was at 0, it was still reported back (my solution didn't, but your challenge appears to require it). Note: I'll clean up some of my comments above, this is getting a bit messy :)

Comment: Thank you very much, impressive solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Your depth variable is locally scoped to the function and gets set to 0 each time the function is called. You need to pass the depth variable down the recursion so that it increments properly. Something like:

```
<?php

function freqCount($arr, $el) {
$depth = 0;
recurse($arr, $el, $depth);

}

function recurse($a, $e, $depth) {

    $counter = 0;
    $result = [];
    
    foreach($a as $k => $v) {
        if(!is_array($v) && $v === $e) {
            $counter++;
            $result[$depth] = $counter;
        } elseif(is_array($v)) {
            $depth++;
            recurse($v, $e, $depth);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);

}
```